# Flow to Delete Leads doesn't seem to work as hoped

Tags: formula, visual-workflow, leads, bulk-delete

**I'm creating a scheduled daily flow that loops through all Leads each day, and if a formula field I created for a deletion date is hit, then delete said Lead.**
[image: Flow Map]

**I'm including an entrance filter to only loop through non-converted Leads:**
[image: Object and Filter]

**I'm collecting my list to a variable, as seen below.**
[image: Loop]

**I then have it making a decision if it needs to be deleted or not based on that formula field I previously mentioned.**
[image: Decision Element]

**And then I run this Delete Records Element.**
[image: Delete Element]

**The Error email I got this morning gave me this conclusion, and I'm not sure why:**

```
DECISION: Needs_to_be_Deleted
Outcome executed: To_Be_Deleted
Outcome conditions: 
{!$Record.To_Be_Deleted__c} (September 29, 2020) Equals {!$Flow.CurrentDate} (September 29, 2020)
FAST DELETE: Delete_these_Leads
Delete Lead records whose IDs are stored in {!LeadstobeDeleted}.
Variable Values
None.
Result
Failed to delete records whose IDs are in {!LeadstobeDeleted}.
```

**I would love any help or advice on this!**

Answer (score 1):

Scheduled flows execute a separate flow interview for every record that meets your entrance criteria so a loop is wholly unnecessary as you will only work with a single record in any flow interview.

What I would suggest instead is adding a formula checkbox to your Lead Record that is set to true when Lead.To_be_Deleted__c = TODAY() and then use THAT checkbox as your flow entry criterion. From there, all you need to do is a Record Delete using the global variable $Record.

The $Record variable is a placeholder for "whatever record triggered this flow interview" and much like other places in flow, when you select it there will automatically be a dot "." behind it. Backspace out the dot so you're deleting " $Record " which is the entire record. If you were to use " $Record.Id " you would be trying to tell Salesforce to just delete the Id field of that record, which will cause an error.